# How to use MongoDB aggregation to find common items between one document and all others?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Now there is a likes collection, and the information recorded in it is as follows.

```
// 1
{
    "_id": ObjectId("1"), 
    "masterid": ObjectId("45678"), // user _id of the owner of the moment
    "momentid": ObjectId("123456"),// moment id
    "userid": ObjectId("123456"), // User _ID of the liker
    "avatar": "1660531471959.jpg", // avatar of the liker
    "username": "userA", // usernameof the liker
    "timestamp": NumberInt("1677072930") // Timestamp of the like
}

// 2
{
    "_id": ObjectId("63f61d8d99b4ee0004e76e03"),
    "masterid": ObjectId("45678"),
    "momentid": ObjectId("123456"),
    "userid": ObjectId("45678"),
    "avatar": "defaultAvatar.jpg",
    "username": "userB",
    "timestamp": NumberInt("1677073805")
}
```

For example, User A likes Moments S and X, while User B likes Moment S and User C likes Moments S, X, and Y. All of them have moments that they both like. I want to query which users have common likes with User A and who has the most common likes with User A.

I want to find other users who have liked the same moments as user A, and then determine the number of moments that they have both liked, and finally find out who among them has liked the most moments in common with user A.

Please help me, this problem has been bothering me for a long time

I have tried the following approach, but it was not successful

```
db.likes.aggregate([

  { $match: { userid: ObjectId("id") } },

  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$momentid",
      count: { $sum: 1 },
      users: { $addToSet: "$userid" }
    }
  },
  
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "likes",
      let: { users: "$users", momentid: "$_id" },
      pipeline: [
        { $match: { $expr: { $and: [
          { $eq: [ "$momentid", "$$momentid" ] },
          { $ne: [ "$userid", ObjectId("id") ] },
          { $in: [ "$userid", "$$users" ] }
        ] } } },
        { $project: { _id: 0, userid: 1 } }
      ],
      as: "otherLikes"
    }
  },
 
  {
    $project: {
      _id: "$moment.userid",
      count: { $size: "$otherLikes.userid" },
      users: "$otherLikes.userid"
    }
  },
  
  { $sort: { count: -1 } }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `$setWindowFields` for this:

1. `$group` by users
2. Mark the wanted user as `type` 0 and all other users with `type` 1
3. Use `$setWindowFields` to set the wanted user's moments to all other users as `chosenUser`
4. Remove the wanted user itself
5. Find for each user the common moments with the wanted user.
6. `$sort` by number of common moments

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$group: {_id: "$userid", moments: {$push: "$momentid"}}},
  {$set: {type: {$cond: [{$eq: ["$_id", ObjectId("id")]}, 0, 1]}}},
  {$setWindowFields: {
      sortBy: {type: 1},
      output: {chosenUser: {
          $first: "$moments",
          window: {range: [-1, 0]}
      }}
  }},
  {$skip: 1},
  {$project: {common: {$setIntersection: ["$chosenUser", "$moments"]}}},
  {$set: {commonSize: {$size: "$common"}}},
  {$sort: {commonSize: -1}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yHsQIXWZFM-)